# D-pad and capture button of my left joy-con are not working properly

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch

History: The SL+SR of my left joy-con is not working and the LED-indicator is not lighting up. The drift of the joystick is also prominent. I bought online a ribbon cable replacement for SL+SR, shell replacement, and a pair of Gulikit joystick replacement that should fix these issues.

I successfully replaced the shell and joystick of my right joy-con. I thought I will also be successful with the left joy-con, but when I tried to use it, it randomly takes screenshots/screen capture and the d-pad sometimes doesn't work.

Anyone here encountered this issue before? How did you fix it? Is the d-pad and screen capture buttons dependent with the motherboard (unlike the SL+SR with separate ribbon cable/module that I can replace).